# Cannot import a component by typing

Tags: javascript, python, html, css, reactjs

When I am importing a module in reactjs by typing `import React, from` 'react';` in from it is showing me error and the code won't work but if I copy paste it the code works perfectly...

What might be the reason ?

Comment: May be you have spelling mistake. Provide your code for better understanding.

Comment: Okay, what's the error say? Maybe you just have a typo and it was auto-corrected on pasting by your editor? You want `import React from 'react';` not `import React, from 'react';` (no comma)

Answer (score 2):

It is enough to write like this:

```
import React from 'react';
```

and if you want to import more modules, you can do like this example:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want import react, use this:

```
import React from "react";
```

no need coma

Answer (score 0):

just only `React` no comma

```
import React from 'react';
```